# Adding classes to LI with JQuery LI to every 7th item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this code to add a class to every 7th LI items and the first one too:

```
$('ul li:first, ul li:nth-child(7n)').addClass("first"); 
$('ul li:first, ul li:nth-child(1)').addClass("first");
```

My problem is that it just adds the class to the 1st and the 7th item but if I add another 7 or more it doesn't add it.

I need to add the class the every 7th li item.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
$('ul li:nth-child(7n+1)').addClass("first");
```

This will select every 7th element.

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/R6DVh/1/) on jsFiddle.

Comment: it looks like the first selector can be removed.

Comment: No, this will not select first `<li>` element then.

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery **eq**

The result of this call id adding a class first to every  item 7. Note that the supplied index is zero-based, and refers to the position of the element within the jQuery object, not within the DOM tree.

```
 $('ul li').eq(6).addClass("first");
```

Comment: No, this will select only 7th item. If you add more items they will be without class

Comment: but this should be in loop, so it will insert to class first to each 7 item. that is only idea. the poster can get some clue.